# How can one use Pyautogui to update Libreoffice Calc?

Tags: python3, libreoffice

Is it possible to use pyautogui to read and update data from libreoffice calc file? If yes, how?

Comment: Do you want to read from a file, or from a running application?

Comment: From a running application. It would be okay also if Python could force Libre to save the file, update the file from Python and force Libre to reload the csv.

Comment: I have implemented something like this on Windows with OLE, but I don't know the Linux approach :(